# Same definition in both GIVEN and THEN ... any way to write a single method?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd

I have this code :

```
Given /^I wait for (\d+) seconds$/ do |seconds|
    $webClient.wait(seconds)
end
Then /^I wait for (\d+) seconds$/ do |seconds|
    $webClient.wait(seconds)
end
```

Can I somehow define it in a single method covering both THEN and GIVEN ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to define the same step twice.  The Given/When/Then are mainly syntactic sugar.

```
Given /^I wait for (\d+) seconds$/ do |seconds|
  $webClient.wait(seconds)
end
```

With the above step, any of the following in your feature will work as expected:

```
Given I wait for 15 seconds
When I wait for 12 seconds
And I wait for 8 seconds
Then I wait for 999 seconds
```

Comment: Ahh ... thanks, I didn't had defined neither Given and When and after running cucumber it suggested to create both of them :


`You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given /^I wait for (\d+) seconds$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Then /^I wait for (\d+) seconds$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end`